# Change the color of asterisk symbol for required Input Fields and FormDropdown in Fluent UI Components

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am using `FluentUI` components for developing Teams App.
And have a form where I need to mark some `Input` and `FormDropdown` fields as required.
On adding `required` flag, the required fields sign `(*)` comes up beside the field label in default i.e black color.
I want to restyle this asterisk sign and change the color of the sign to red.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subComponentStyles` property inside `styles` to modify styles of `Label` component:

```js
<TextField
  label="Required "
  required={true}
  styles={{
    subComponentStyles: {
      label: {
        root: {
          ':after': {
             position: 'absolute',
             content: `'@'`,
             color: 'green'
          }
        },
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

**ComboBox**

```js
<ComboBox
   label="Foo"
   required={true}
   styles={{
     label: {
       ':after': {
          position: 'absolute',
          content: `'@'`,
          color: 'green',
        },
     },
   }}
/>
```

Approach is the same for Dropdown component.

[Codepen working](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/NWYZrXq?editors=0010) example.

[Label Component](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/react/src/components/Label/Label.styles.ts#L40) implementation.

[TextField areaLabel](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/react/src/components/TextField/TextField.styles.tsx#L274) implementation.

Comment: I use same code ComboBox but get Typescript error Type '{ subComponentStyles: { label: { root: { ':after': { position: string; content: string; color: string; fontSize: string; }; }; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<IComboBoxStyles>'

Comment: @OferGal `ComboBox` has different approach. Check answer.